# General formula for the value of the $n$th derivative at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, summation, generating-functions

Can anyone show me how to derive this summation for the value of the $n$th derivative at $x=0$ for this function:

$\frac{d}{dx^n}(\exp({\frac{x^2}{2}+x}))$ is this sum:

$\frac{d}{dx^n}(\exp({\frac{x^2}{2}+x})) =$ $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}} \frac{1}{2^kx^{2k}k!(-2k+n)!}$

[Screenshot from wolfram alpha for the sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5tUc.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f(x) = e^{x^2/2}$ and $g(x) = e^x$.  Then $$(fg)^{(n)}(0) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f^{(k)}(0) g^{(n-k)}(0)$$ by the extended product rule.  Now $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(x^2/2)^k}{k!}, \quad g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!},$$ and by Taylor's theorem it follows that $$f^{(k)}(0) = \begin{cases}0, & k \text{ odd}, \newline \frac{k!}{2^{k/2} (k/2)!}, & k \text{ even}.\end{cases}$$  We also have of course $g^{(n-k)}(0) = 1$.  Then $$(fg)^{(n)}(0) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2k} \frac{(2k)!}{2^k k!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \frac{n!}{k!(n-2k)!2^k}.$$

Comment: how did u get ⌊n/2⌋ in the upper limit

Comment: Can you explain the Taylor's theorem part about odd and even

Answer (score 4):

One way is to define the sequence of polynomials
$\,P_n(x)\,$ such that
$$ P_n(x)\,e^{x+x^2/2} = \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n e^{x+x^2/2}. $$ The coefficients of the polynomial sequence is the [OEIS sequence A111062](https://oeis.org/A111062). Please consult the OEIS entry for more details. Of course, the function $\,e^{x+x^2/2}\,$ itself is the exponential generating function for the [OEIS sequence A000085](https://oeis.org/A000085). The OEIS entry gives the summation formula
$$ a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \frac{n!}{(n-2k)! 2^k k!}$$ which you already got from Wolfram|Alpha. Probably the easiest method is to find the power series for $\,e^x\,$ and
 $\,e^{x^2/2}\,$ and multiply them which will produce the formula.

More precisely, consider
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\, \frac{x^n}{n!}
 := e^{x+x^2/2} = e^x\,e^{x^2/2}= \\
 \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!}
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{2^k k!}
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} 
\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \frac{n!}{(n-2k)! 2^k k!}
$$ where $\,j = n-2k.\,$ Since we have
 $\,0\le j,\,0\le k,\,$ and $\,k=(n-j)/2,\,$ then
we must have $\,0\le k\le n/2.$

Comment: Any connection with Hermite polynomials (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, there are definite connections to Hermite Polynomials. In fact, there is a theory of polynomials with definition similar to both of them.

Comment: How did you get the upper limit of the sum as (n/2)

Comment: @ThaqibDamani2.0  Okay, I added last sentence about that. Thanks for asking.